# print only certain positions in array in C

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I have been googling for a few days trying to find the correct syntax in C. to print an array in a set out of order arrangement. I am  new to C but know php, Java well. Am I using the wrong logic approach?

What I would like to print out is

```
     "Here is your order, 2B 3C 1A"
```

I have tried using the following type of code but get,

```
     @[2] (null)[3] (null)[1]
     segmentation fault

     char *aa="1A";
     char *bb="2B";
     char *cc="3C";
     char * zz[]={aa,bb,cc};
     g_print("Here is your order, %s[2] %s[3] %s[1]",zz);
```

thanks
Art

Comment: `for(i=0;i<3;i++) printf("%s ", zz[i]);`, change the order you like.

Comment: ... and read the documentation of printf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to print each string in the array:

```
g_print("Here is your order, %s %s %s",zz[1], zz[2], zz[0]);
```

Note the indexing!

If the number of items is set during runtime, you have to use a loop:

```
g_print("Here is your order,");
for (size_t i = 0; i < some_upper_limit; ++i)
    g_print(" %s", zz[i]);
```

---

Also note that you declare the `aa`, `bb` and `cc` variables wrong. You should either declare them as arrays, or as pointers to constant strings. That's because string literals are constant.

So:

```
char aa[]="1A";
char bb[]="2B";
char cc[]="3C";
```

or

```
const char *aa="1A";
const char *bb="2B";
const char *cc="3C";
```

Comment: thanks @Joachim Pileborg for the two alt's, now it makes sense. thx Art

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
 g_print("Here is your order, %s %s %s",zz[1], zz[2], zz[0]);
```

array indices start with 0. The contents of strings is not evaluated for the array indices.